# Looking for indian high-school or college math textbooks freely available online .

Tags: reference-request, soft-question

After having seen a Youtube video on a very difficult math exam in india, I'm curious to see how math are taught in this country. ( Link : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IpeL1prh2SY)

Is there any available free high school or college math textbook on line?

I mean some textbook edited by the educational board of some province of india, as I have seen it is the case sometimes for economics or logic ( and surely other subjects).

Thanks.

Comment: Being an indian, i can say you (mostly) high school math is taught in such a way, hatred towards the subject will be immediate

Comment: However, indian textbooks I have had the opportunity to look at were very clear and reader friendly.

Comment: Yeah the textbooks are nice, but sadly mostly they are not conveyed to us in proper way. Our school math teacher literally remembers laws of exponents(To be precise our class math teacher)

Comment: Remember or do not remember? What do you mean ?

Comment: I mean, if your teachers remember these laws, it seems to be a good thing, no?

Comment: She memorises and thus sometimes blunders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the National Council of Educational Research and Training, that decides the syllabus, and publishes content of secondary and senior-secondary students.
You can check their site for E-Books http://ncert.nic.in/textbook/textbook.htm?lemh1=0-6
These are mandatory books in high school and examinations are conducted based on them, yet interested students follow some other books as well.

Comment: Thanks for this ressource!

Answer (score 1):

I think that there is a misunderstanding of how math is taught in our country, it's not as intensive as you think. JEE is an exam which is taken by million students but only $11,000$ get selected. So if you require books of **JEE Advanced** standard then better go for books which are exclusively cooked up for it. And not definitely basic theory books such as NCERT as mentioned by others. NCERT is a common book for all high school students, which may reach about $6$ million(not so sure)

Some books which jee aspirants follow are given in this [link](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-best-books-that-can-be-referred-to-for-JEE-Mains-and-Advanced-for-preparation-in-Physics-Chemistry-and-Mathematics) it includes some old books and i think all the pdf are available online. I would recommend cengage series in math for jee advanced

Comment: The JEE test that is referred to in the video is what occasioned my question. But , in fact, I'm more interested in standard ( though possibly high level) high school or college indian math books. - Thaks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, going by the video you posted, I will assume that you wish to explore more competition oriented resources. The one resource for IIT-JEE exam is [TMH Jee Advanced](https://www.iitmind.com/2018/12/tmh-iitjee-mathematics-pdf.html) and this is the book I recommend the most for IIT JEE aspirants. It primarily is a problem book and that too unstructured but it captures the spirit and essence of IIT JEE.

Answer (score 0):

These books covers the essence of what you are looking for. Almost everybody in 11th and 12th study from these books.

https://jeemain.guru/best-books-for-mathematics-part-1/

PS- The books written by NCERT are basic books suitable for self study. I may add, NCERT also publishes Exemplar problems books (For Class 11th , and 12th) which is tougher version of those basic books for 11th and 12th.